# ModuleNotFoundError - different behavior between script and REPL

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have done a bit of googling and SO searches and can't seem to find a way to (outside of modifying PATH or PYTHONPATH) avoid the `ModuleNotFoundError` when running the application as a script.  Everything seems to work fine when run through the REPL, however.  Is there not a good way to do this or do I just have to accept the fact that my application's PYTHONPATH needs to be predefined?  If modifying the PYTHONPATH is the best way, where might i set this within the below sample application?

And to clarify, this is not a "its broke, help fix it" question, this is a "how best to approach this" question.

A sample application:

```
.
└── mnf_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── dir1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── mod1.py
    └── dir2
        ├── __init__.py
        └── mod2.py

# mnf_app/dir1/mod1.py
from mnf_app.dir2 import mod2

print('hello from', __file__)

# mnf_app/dir2/mod2.py
print('hello from', __file__)
```

## Everything works fine from the REPL (without modifying PATH or PYTHONPATH)

```
$ python
>>> import mnf_app.dir1.mod1
hello from /private/tmp/mnf-app/mnf_app/dir2/mod2.py
hello from /private/tmp/mnf-app/mnf_app/dir1/mod1.py
```

## Fails with ModuleNotFoundError when trying to run as a script

```
$ python mnf_app/dir1/mod1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnf_app/dir1/mod1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mnf_app.dir2 import mod2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mnf_app'
```

## works fine when modifying PYTHONPATH

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/mnf-app
$ python mnf_app/dir1/mod1.py
hello from /tmp/mnf-app/mnf_app/dir2/mod2.py
hello from mnf_app/dir1/mod1.py
```

Comment: I suppose you answered your own question with "works fine when modifying PYTHONPATH"

Comment: And note that modules import work different between python versions. Look at [David Beazley presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/modulepackage) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: @AlexYu Is this the best practice?  If so, I suppose I can live with that but where would I set PYTHONPATH in the program?  This app will ultimately be a command-line application used by any number of unknown users so we can't expect that they will have PYTHONPATH predefined.  (And thanks for the video reference, I will check it out).

Comment: Best practice is to use setuptools to manage package and use the "developer mode" to set up the paths to point to your local workspace.

Comment: Also, don't run a module from a package directly like that. Nobody would ever do that. use `python -m mnf_app.dir1.mod1`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in manipulating environment variables. You can even do one-liner: `export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/mnf-app python mnf_app/dir1/mod1.py`. Or you can use `.env`-files. Although I recommend to use `pipenv` + `.env` for most types of python projects

Comment: After a little thought: yes, I can recommen you to master using of `.env`-files. This is one of the "best practices" today. But this is another question.

Comment: @AlexYu Could you please provide any recommended resources to get started with `.env`?

Comment: Start use [direnv](https://direnv.net) - it's just great. Look at [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/0.1.0) - it's just works.